# Is magento 2.3.2 backward compatible with 2.3.1?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

All the extensions and the theme officially support 2.3.1, I had no option but to install extensions because the client wants multivendor system with reservation and POS.

The day I finished installation and everything got working correctly, magento 2.3.2 dropped, can I update or not? I can backup and try obviously, but I just want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento uses semantic versioning by module (which is different from the published marketing version number). Each module has a version like `101.0.1`, and breaking changes will increase the first version number.

If you use composer packages and declare your dependencies, you can use composer and version constraints to detect that.

If not: It depends, but generally minor point releases like 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 involve minimal backwards-incompatible changes and are fairly safe to apply.

That being said, that only applies to Magento's official 'service layer'. Some extensions interface with Magento at a much deeper internal level, where they can change things without it being considered a breaking change, and if that's the case all bets are off. All you can do in that case is apply the update, test your extensions, and see what happens.